# Why can Java 8 load Java 9 class?

Tags: java, unsupported-class-version

I have following setting:

Class A - compiled with java 9 (class version 53)
Class B - Should be compiled with java 8 (class version 52)

Class B has a dependency to Class A.

Now I get a surprising result:
I can successfully compile Class B with Java 8 although it has a dependency to the java 9 compiled class A.

If I compile Class A with Java 10 or Java 11 and then try to compile class B with Java 8 I get the expected error message:

class file has wrong version 55.0 (or 54.0), should be 52.0

So can anybody explain why I don't get the message

class file has wrong version 53.0, should be 52.0

if I try to use Java 8 with Java 9 classes?

I use this java versions:

Java 8:  Oracle jdk 1.8.0_144   (installed in folder d:\jdk8)
Java 9:  Oracle jdk 9.0.1       (installed in folder d:\jdk9)
Java 11: Oracle jdk 11.0.1      (installed in folder d:\jdk11)

To demonstrate it I created this two class files:

File A.java:

```
public class A {
    public void test() {
        System.out.println("Class A");
    }
}
```

File B.java:

```
public class B {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        A classA = new A();
        classA.test();

        System.out.println("Class B");
    }
}
```

First A.java is compiled with Java 9:
d:\jdk9\bin>javac d:\test\A.java

Then B.java is compiled with Java 8 using the Class A that is compiled with Java 9:
d:\jdk8\bin>javac -cp d:\test d:\test\B.java

warning: d:\test\A.class: major version 53 is newer than 52, the highest major version supported by this compiler.
  It is recommended that the compiler be upgraded.
1 warning

So the class file is compiled successfully with a warning. I just saw this warning by invoking the compiler manually. If I use Maven to build the project,
this warning wasn't visible.

Now Class A is compiled with Java 11 (same with Java 10):
d:\jdk11\bin>javac d:\test\A.java

If I try to compile Class B, I get an error:

d:\jdk8\bin>javac -cp d:\test d:\test\B.java

d:\test\B.java:3: error: cannot access A
        A classA = new A();
        ^
  bad class file: d:\test\A.class
    class file has wrong version 55.0, should be 52.0
    Please remove or make sure it appears in the correct subdirectory of the classpath.
1 error

So it seems that technically it's possible to use Java 9 compiled class files with Java 8. But I did not think it was possible.

Comment: I'm assuming you are talking about some sort of libraries? Can you give the specific case where this occurs?

Comment: what is the ```javac``` and ```java``` version on your machine, where you are compiling the class B ?

Comment: How do you compile your classes?

Comment: I added the compiler versions with examples to my initial post.

Answer (score 1):

The java 9 compiler [`javac`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/tools/javac.htm#GUID-AEEC9F07-CB49-4E96-8BC7-BCC2C7F725C9__BHCGAJDC) probably compiled for java 8; one can use a newer compiler to compile for an older .class version. Look for **-target** and **-source** 1.8.

Either the IDE or maven/gradle was configured for an older version.

Comment: I think this wasn't the case here. I looked in the class file with a hex editor and saw that the class version is really 53.0 -> java9.

Comment: You mentioned that manual compilation went wrong and maven went through, so maven seems to have a setting, either in the pom, some properties, or even settings.xml. Mind, the .class files of maven might be at another spot.

Comment: I mentioned that in both cases (manually and Maven build), the "Java 8 with Java 9 classes" went through. I only saw the warning in the manual case. And in both cases the "Java 8 with java 11 classes" failed.

Comment: Sorry, I still find it hard to believe that **java** of version 8 can do classes of version 9. With the new release scheme it might come to that, but maybe someone else might shed some light on this topic. Trying it out in a test project.

Comment: I couldn't believe it, too. That's why I posted here ;-) But the warning indicates that Java 8 is aware that it uses newer class files (at least Java 9 classes) but it doesn't fail to compile. I couldn't get any information on this in the Java documentation.